# Lost dollar signs in terminal on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, virtualenv

I was messing around in the terminal on my mac with virtualenv but now I lost the dollar signs on the command line!

Does anybody know what this means and how I can get them back? I already tried rebooting but that didn't help.

Btw, I'm using zshell.

[image: Lost dollar signs]

Comment: What is your `$PS1` set to?

Comment: Not sure what my $PS1 is but I searched for it in my .zshrc file and I couldn't find it

Comment: ○ echo $PS1

%{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%} at %{$fg[yellow]%}%m%{$reset_color%} in %{$fg_bold[green]%}$(collapse_pwd)%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info)
$(virtualenv_info)$(prompt_char) This what that command gives

Comment: Well, what is `$prompt_char` set to? That is probably the issue. Then you should check your config file to set it to what you want.

Comment: I tried echo $prompt_char but it didn't show me anything and it is not in my .zshrc file

Comment: And if you set it too `\$`...?

Answer (score 0):

If its a problem with your bash startup scripts, then from terminal menu item, Select "New Command" and run "bash --noprofile --norc"

Answer (score 0):

try pasting 'bash --noprofile --norc' and return, then paste 'chsh -s /bin/zsh'  and return. It should ask you for your password